# Are centre-surround antagonism and lateral inhibition synonyms?

Tags: neuroscience, perception, neurophysiology, sensation, sensory-perception

On Wikipedia, there is one page for [centre-surround antagonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center-surround_antagonism) and one for [lateral inhibition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_inhibition). They both concern the activity of a neuron being reduced by stimuli present not in the center of its receptive field but near its periphery.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**
The term **[center-surround antagonism](https://www.cns.nyu.edu/%7Edavid/courses/perception/lecturenotes/ganglion/ganglion.html)** is a specific example of the more general term [**lateral inhibition**](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-0-387-79948-3_1379#:%7E:text=Definition,stimulated%20and%20least%20inhibited%20respond.).

**Background**
The term 'center-surround' is used [specifically for retinal connectivity](https://pressbooks.umn.edu/sensationandperception/chapter/lateral-inhibition-draft/) and visual processing. Specifically, it enhances contrast perception by exaggerating differences in light responses.

Lateral inhibition includes center-surround antagonism observed in the retina, but is a [more general term](https://dictionary.apa.org/lateral-inhibition) also applied for similar processes occurring in other sensory systems, like the tactile senses.

Answer (score -1):

The two are similar in some ways, but most definitely different in reality. Presenting stimuli near the periphery of a sensory neuron's receptive field (RF) can indeed lead to inhibit its activity (i.e. reduce its action potential discharge rate) through both of these mechanisms, but the mechanisms operate differently.

Centre-surround antagonism is independent from other nearby neurons. If a single neuron were isolated and a stimulus presented in its receptive field surround, its activity would get inhibited.

Lateral inhibition, on the other hand, doesn't talk directly about the RF, but rather about neighboring neurons *in the brain*. The "lateral" doesn't refer to geometric proximity, but rather to so-called lateral connections (i.e. at the same level of abstraction in cognitive processing) between neurons in the brain.

In truth, receptive fields can overlap, and due to "x-topies" (somatotopy, retinotopy, tonotopy, etc.), both mechanisms can end up active at the same time (but not always!).